# How to enable `eslint` to parse spread operator?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using `eslint` for a javascript project. `eslint` failed to parse spread operator and I got this error `11:18  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token ..`.

The code for above error is:

```
return { ...render }
```

The eslint configuration is yml file:

```
env:
  browser: true
  es6: true
extends: 'eslint:recommended'
parserOptions:
  ecmaVersion: 2017
  sourceType: module
  experimentalObjectRestSpread: true
rules:
  indent:
    - error
    - 4
  linebreak-style:
    - error
    - unix
  quotes:
    - error
    - single
  semi:
    - error
    - always
  no-console:
    - off
  prefer-spread: "error"
```

Comment: Which version of ESLint are you using?

Answer (score 6):

This is related to [ESLint doesn't support spread operator in objects #10307](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10307), where full description of various alternatives on how to fix it is listed.

Essentially it boils down to changing to `ecmaVersion: 2018` (or the equivalent `ecmaVersion: 9`), which is when it first was officially supported. With this change there is also no need for the `experimentalObjectRestSpread: true` any more.

Comment: Unfortunately `ecmaVersion: 2018` hasn't helped me avoid `...calculateStatsPerFile(messages) ^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...`, and that linked issue didn't help either.

Comment: Changed to 'ecmaVersion: 9' and it works like a magic, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is fixed by add configuration: `parser: 'babel-eslint'`

Comment: You shouldn’t need to change the parser to get spread support.